# JavaScript -- is this radio button checked?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, radio-button

I'm trying to get the data on the user's selection from a radio form. Here is what I have tried.

```
<form id="office">
    <label id="ques1"> question 1</label>
        <div class="q1 wrong q1a1"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a1" /> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q1 wrong q1a2"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a2" /> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q1 wrong q1a3"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a3" /> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q1 right q1a4"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a4" /> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submitAnswers" value="Submit Your Answers" onclick="checkFunction()" />
</form>
<script>
var answersQ01 = document.getElementsById(q1a1).value;

function checkFunction()
{
if (answersQ01.checked) {/*here i would like to know if it's checked or not*/}

};
```

Which doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on how to approach this?
I would rather, if possible, have my answers in HTML and JavaScript since I don't know PHP or jQuery.

Thanks a lot!

P.S 
I've put each input in a div, so that I can give them separate designs in CSS.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Move the `q1a1` class name to an id attribute.

Comment: I'm writing an answer right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, I will improve it if it doesn't work for you. (code snippets don't let you use the `form` tag).

```js
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
    if (document.getElementById('q1a1').checked == true) {
      console.log('checked');
    } else {
      console.log('not checked');
    }
  };
};
```

```html
<!--<form id="office">-->
<label id="ques1">question 1</label>
<div class="q1 wrong q1a1">
  <input type="radio" name="question1" id="q1a1" value="q1a1" />Answer1
  <br/>
</div>
<div class="q1 wrong q1a2">
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a2" />Answer2
  <br/>
</div>
<div class="q1 wrong q1a3">
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a3" />Answer3
  <br/>
</div>
<div class="q1 right q1a4">
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a4" />Answer4
  <br/>
</div>

<br/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submitAnswers" value="Submit Your Answers" />
<!--</form>-->
```

Comment: i don't know how to check if it's working... could i do somthing like this?

window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
    if (document.getElementById('q1a1').checked == true) {
      console.log('checked');
   alert ("OK");
    } else {
      console.log('not checked');
   alert ("NOT OK")
    }
  };
};



thank you so much!

Comment: Sure you can. `alert();` doesn't work in a stackoverflow code snippet which is why I used `console.log`. This code is only setup to work with one radio button but you/I could set it up to work as a generic algorithm for all the radio buttons. I.E. make it check all the radio buttons instead of just one.

Comment: You always want to put your code inside an onload function to prevent it from running before the rest of the page loads. If you want to have multiple instances of the load event, you can use `window.addEventListener('load',function(){/*code here*/});`. My code only allows you to have one `onload` function. You should avoid using inline events, rather use scripted functions.

Comment: Just replace the `console.log()` with your alert. Console.log logs message to the browsers console used mostly for debugging of web pages.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were a great help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector` to get the checked radio button.Here is the snippet for you

```
    function checkFunction(){
    var checkedValue='';
    var getCheckedButton= document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked');
    if(getCheckedButton !==null){
    checkedValue = getCheckedButton.value;
    }
    console.log(checkedValue);
   }
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gebd8LLt/4/)